# How to divide a number by every number in an array?

Tags: javascript

Let's say x = 120, and you have an array: [1,2,3,4,5].

Id like to create an array that has the results of 120 divided by every number in the array individually, so it produces

[120, 60, 40, 30, 24]?

Comment: Have you tried anything? Show us your code and explain what's not working about it.

Answer (score 3):

You could use [`Array.prototype.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

*Using ES5:*

```
var dividedBy120 = [1,2,3,4,5].map(function(currentValue, index, array){
  return 120/currentValue;
});
// dividedBy120 = [120, 60, 40, 30, 24]
```

*Using ES6 arrow function:*

```
var dividedBy120 = [1,2,3,4,5].map(currentValue => 120/currentValue);
// dividedBy120 = [120, 60, 40, 30, 24]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```
 var array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
 var division_results = []; // The results are stored here.

    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
        var result = 120 / array[i]; // This is the result of the division.
        division_results.push(result);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use Array.prototype.[map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

```
var dividend = 120;
var divisors = [1,2,3,4,5];
```

ES5

```
var quotients = divisors.map(function(divisor){
    return dividend / divisor;
);
```

ES6

```
var quotients = divisors.map(divisor=> dividend / divisor);
```